# No.of occurrence in a file using windows search service

Tags: c#, windows, indexing, system, windows-search

I am using windows search service to get the data from a particular folder and using the below query

SELECT System.ItemName,System.ItemType,RANK,System.ItemPathDisplay   FROM SystemIndex WHERE directory = 'file:C:/Test/'  and CONTAINS ('Swiggy')

Here I want to get the no. occurrence in the select clause based on the keyword which I used in Contains.

Meaning I need to find out How many places the key word (Swiggy) is present in my file

I have noticed the RANK column which is giving based on some other logic. 
Can any one help me to get the Count.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc465173(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Can you help me with an example.

Comment: If you can provide a more complete code sample, I can try to work out a more complete solution, I haven't used Windows Search.

Comment: Thanks! Alexandru... I have checked in internet and found one solution for my question in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521715(v=vs.85).aspx 
There is one column System.Search.HitCount which I have used to sort the data and now I am getting the data as expected

Comment: Glad to hear it! Now you can also add an answer for future visitors :) hint: links die, write a summary of what you did, maybe a code sample

Answer (score 1):

You can reference System.Search.HitCount if you use the CONTAINS type of SELECT query.
Otherwise, the System.Search.Rank will return a ranking relevance from 0 to 1000 (where higher is better relevance).